# filesystem encryption over the wires

Tags: encryption, filesystems, truecrypt

lets assume the following scenario; i need to open a encrypted filesystem (like i'm able to do with TrueCrypt locally) over a network, but

- i want the encryption/decryption to happen strictly in the client, so no magic tokens get outside my machine
- i want to read/write the filesystem on-demand basis: my encrypted filesystem might contain 3Gb of files, but i only need to edit a file of 1Mb, so my bandwidth consumption should not exceed a significant portion of that

it seems to me the only way to satisfy both requirement is with block-level encryption, so the client will decrypt the filesystem structure, request specific blocks over the network, edit some of the requested blocks, send updated (already encrypted) blocks.

What tools do exist for that? I've heard that eCryptFS does block-level encryption, but i'm not sure if there is a nice frontend for it as with TrueCrypt

My understanding is that with TrueCrypt you would need to download the full 3Gb partition, open it, edit some files, unmount and then resend the whole 3Gb. Is this correct?

Comment: Are you looking for some software, or are you asking how to write such software?

Comment: a existing library would be ok

Answer (score 2):

You can use a protocol that allows you to connect to a raw disk over the network, then run a standard partition-encryption tool (like TrueCrypt) on top of that.

Examples of such protocols are NBD (Network Block Device) and iSCSI (SCSI over IP).

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a file system library, than our [SolFS](http://www.eldos.com/solfs/) offers exactly what you need. You can keep the storage on the server (encrypted) and open it from the client. When opening, only some pages will be downloaded and they will be decrypted on the client side (and re-encrypted and uploaded back upon change).

Answer (score 1):

[Network block devices](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Network_block_device) should make this possible. Not sure how stable that protocol is or whether it even supports multiple clients.